# How to make sendmail respect +-notation for virtual users?

Tags: sendmail, mail-forwarding

I have different forwarding needs for different domains, which all point to my mail-server:

```
user1@example.com   foo@example.org
user2@example.com   bar@example.net
@example.com        mylocalaccount
```

This all works... However, some of these users wish to use the +-notation to give different vendors different addresses, such as `user1`+*vendor*`@example.com`. And this part is not working -- all such e-mails end up delivered to the catchall `mylocalaccount` instead of being forwarded properly.

How do I make `user+foo@example.com` be forwarded to the same destination as `user@example.com`?

I tried adding entries like

```
user1+*@example.com    foo+%2@example.org
```

but that didn't fix the problem...

Here are the debug-traces:

#### Without the detail:

```
% sendmail -d60.5 -bv g@example.com
map_lookup(dequote, me, %0=me) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(dequote, g, %0=g) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(virtuser, g@example.com, %0=g@example.com, %1=g) => gexample@example.net (0)
```

... works.

#### With the detail:

```
% sendmail -d60.5 -bv g+meow@example.com
map_lookup(dequote, me, %0=me) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(dequote, g+meow, %0=g+meow) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(virtuser, g+meow@example.com, %0=g+meow@example.com, %1=g+meow) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(virtuser, @example.com, %0=@example.com, %1=g+meow) => me (0)
map_lookup(dequote, me, %0=me) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(user, me, %0=me) => me<> (0)
g+meow@example.com... deliverable: mailer local, user me
```

... does not work -- comes to the catch-all local account "me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `+` is missing in `OperatorChars` in your `sendmail.cf`. It makes `R` lines in `sedmail.cf` see one token `user+detail` instead of three tokens `user` `+` `detail`.

`sendmail.cf` generated from `sendmail.mc` **should** set OperatorChars to `.:%@!^/[]+` by default accoding to [the bat book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596510299.do).  It may be changed in mc file by defining `confOPERATORS`.

Check what is reported by `grep OperatorChars /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`

Comment: You may be right -- for the last few years, `sendmail` was warning at start-up about `Warning: OperatorChars is being redefined.` Maybe, I need to address this. But I do not set them explicitly anywhere in the `.mc`-file -- so I'm not sure, how. Also, the `+`-delivery works for the real local users...

Comment: Ok, I hand-edited the `sendmail.cf` to move the `OperatorChars` definition to the very beginning of the file. The above-mentioned warning is gone and the virtuser-delivery works! Much rejoicing, but how do I codify it in my `sendmail.mc`? Thanks!

Comment: `sendmail.cf` generated from *.mc file **should** set OperatorChars right by default (with '+' included'). It seems that something is wrong with your `sendmail.mc` to `sedmail.cf` transition.

Comment: It does generate the default `OperatorChars` line -- but the line appears too late in the file for some reason. I added the line explicitly -- after the `DOMAIN(generic)`, but before the first `FEATURE` -- and now things work! The warning about `OperatorChars` "being redefined" is still there (because the same line now appears _twice_), but it seems harmless.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to virtusertable to redirect **with +detail preserved** then try:

```
# use %2 if you want to strip EMPTY +detail (user+@example.net)
user1@example.com   foo%3@example.org
```

**Debug procedure**
As root execute `sendmail -d60.5 -bv user1+x@example.net`.
It should trace map lookups including virtusertable map lookups.
Try `sendmail -d21.12 -d60.5 -bv user1+x@example.net` if +detail is stripped before virtusertable lookups.

`user1+detail@example.com` by default **should** make sendmail look for the following virtusertable enries:

1. user+detail@example.com
2. user++@example.com
3. user+*@example.com
4. user@example.com
5. ++@example.com
6. +*@example.com
7. @example.com

user+@example.com (plus present but detail empty) conducts lookups 1+3+4+6+7
user@example.com (no +detail present) condutcs lookups 4+7

Comment: The `-d21.12` part makes the output too much for inclusion here, I posted it [online verbatim](http://aldan.algebra.com/~mi/tmp/sendmail-debug-trace.txt). Thanks!